# Deleting folder within a folder after zipping and deleting some files

Tags: php, zip

This is follow-up question after on my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php).

```
Folder
  subfolders
  imagefolder
  important.txt
  index.txt
```

I have a subfolder, How to zip the `Folder`, then delete all files including all the folders within the `Folder` exempt the `important.txt`?

From the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php). I've got this:

```
$zipFile = "./testZip.zip";
$zipArchive = new ZipArchive();

if (!$zipArchive->open($zipFile, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE))
    die("Failed to create archive\n");

$zipArchive->addGlob("./*.txt");
if (!$zipArchive->status == ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OK)
    echo "Failed to write files to zip\n";

$zipArchive->close();
```

But it gave me this output:
`testZip.zip` has been created but including only file: `important.txt`
then the subfolders is not deleted.

Comment: Did you try my approach? You would also have to add a shell('rm -r Folder/subfolders'); to delete the subfolders. Its a very naive approach but also very robust as long as you do not change the folders content.

Comment: that is the problem, i can't use your method since the content of the folders are changing. It's not consistent files..except on the important.txt

Comment: I added an answer that doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but Its not the answer for my problem.I have less than 2 hours in answering this. This is for my school project. I will fail if i don't get this solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the solution I posted in your other question and replace the exec('rm...') call with

```
exec('find Folder -mindepth 1|grep -v important.txt|xargs rm -r');
```

then it will delete all files except important.txt in 'Folder'.