# download a folder using php

Tags: php

I have a folder in my server. How do i zip the folder and download it using php.

Comment: couple similar questions here on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484347/how-to-zip-a-folder-and-download-it-using-php

Comment: Please point out why none of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zip+and+download+folder+[php] answered your question.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 2):

See the [PHP Zip methods](http://php.net/zip).

Example from [PHP manual pages](http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php):

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./test112.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

$zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt" . time(), "#1 This is a test string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
$zip->addFromString("testfilephp2.txt" . time(), "#2 This is a test string added as testfilephp2.txt.\n");
$zip->addFile($thisdir . "/too.php","/testfromfile.php");
echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
$    zip->close();
?>
```