# How to Download and Delete complete folder with javascript/jQuery or php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am creating folder with php script `mkdir()`
and after some time i want to delete complete folder and its content
`Folder name is` **`MYFILES`**
1. How to download complete folder ?
2. How to delete complete folder ?

Comment: You can not delete folder or files creating in server using javascript or jQuery as they run on the client browser side.

Comment: Seems like duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-files-sub-dir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recursively delete a directory and its entire contents (files + sub dirs) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-files-sub-dir)

Comment: @sjaustirni its not duplicate i asking about to download folder too, have you answer then please help

Comment: @MichalCygankiewicz I am asking also about to download complete folder too if any answer then provide

Comment: @DeepakChahar In that case you're asking multiple questions at once and your question is too broad. Please ask one question at a time

Comment: @sjaustirni lol if i had two problems with some code then why should i ask at different time? is it make any sense?

Comment: @DeepakChahar because had you done so, you would have learnt that you don't need to ask any question. Question on how to delete a folder in PHP has been linked above and question on how to download a folder in PHP already [exists as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486199/download-a-folder-using-php). Askers on StackOverflow are discouraged from asking duplicate questions.

Comment: @sjaustirni thanks for that link i searched on google and stack too it didn't give me the solution. Hope that code will work

Comment: @DeepakChahar You are very welcome :D. Please make sure to try more search phrases before posting a question next time. The one I used was *download folder in php*. Good luck with the code!

Comment: @sjaustirni i tried a lot but thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [rmdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php) PHP built in function and pass directory name as the argument and it will delete the folder. If you want to delete files/folders using Codeigniter as per your question tag then you can go through [this documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html) as well.

Note: Several things you need to take care of are: Folder contents, folder permissions etc.

EDIT:

Since you have later requested to download complete folder then all you can do is to zip the folder and force download using `header` function. Check [this documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/zip.html) to create zips from directory.

Comment: @RaviManiyar Please do not answer duplicate questions. Flag them as duplicates instead.