# How to download a zipped file in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to zip a whole folder using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php)

Hi,
I am creating a zip folder using zipArchive in php.The zipped file contains a folder(with a file in it) and a file. I am using the following code to download the zipped file:

```
$file_path = "zip/test.zip";
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=download.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize( $file_path));
readfile($file_path);
```

The folder gets downloaded. But I am unable to unzip it. 
The error specified is "Decompression failed". 
I can download a single file with the same code but not a file within a folder.
Please help..
Here is the code to zip the files:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($file_path,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === TRUE) {

   if($zip->addEmptyDir('dir1')) {
       $zip->addFile($filepath,$destinationPath);
       if($zip->addEmptyDir('Files')) {
           $zip->addFile($filepath2,$destinationPath2);
       } 
   }
}
```

Comment: You should show the code you are using to create the zip file

Comment: I have added the code to zip the files. The paths are predefined

Answer (score 0):

I got the code working...
Need to add a $zip->close() code.

Comment: But [that's done automatically](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-close.php) at the end of the script if you leave it out.