# Insert text file to JAR using php

Tags: php, java-me, jar

I made a j2me code and extracted the jar file ..... jar file will be downloaded online and I need to insert data generated automatically for every download which I can deal with it from J2me code .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What for you need it? I know answer for your question, but I know what for such things being used also.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create the new jar file the same way you would create a zip file (ex. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php) )

If your jar archive is signed, beware that code signing verification fails if content is modified.