# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Help please! I've been retrieving listing in my system from database. But it has thousand listing until this error appear:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

This code is from my htaccess

```
php_value max_execution_time 3000
php_value upload_max_filesize 512M
php_value post_max_size 512M
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value set_time_limit 0
```

How can I resolve this? I'm using PHP and MYSQL.

Comment: are you executing a query and fetching the result in php? try it on the server directly and see how much time it takes for a query to run.

Comment: Is your host configured to allow htaccess overrides? Try a `phpinfo` or `ini_get` to see if the settings are actually taking effect.

Comment: It is possible that you accidentally make an infinite loop. Keep out.

Comment: JW yes. that's exactly that I'm doing.

Comment: How does your code look like? Maybe there is another way around?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you could extend the maximum execution time like this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

else edit your htaccess

```
php_value max_execution_time 0
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this in top of your php file

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

If running php using command line interface (CLI) use:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
```

else run :

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The same error we face in wordpress site

we made changes in the .htaccess but it didn't work.

Then we created one php.ini file interred this code and uploaded to root directory

```
max_execution_time = 60
```

and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the file set the timeout:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```