# Get the Files from a directory and compress them into a ZIP-Package

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

Short explanation:

There are some files in the directory

```
Yii::app()->runtimePath.'/temp/myDir/';
```

These files should be zipped in the same directory like:

```
Yii::app()->runtimePath.'/temp/myDir/files.zip
```

Following construction gives no errors, but zip-file is not created.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$path = Yii::app()->runtimePath.'/temp/myDir/';

// Open an empty ZIP-File to write into
$ret = $zip->open('files.zip', ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

if ($ret !== TRUE) {
    printf('Failed with code %d', $ret);
} else {
    $options = array('add_path' => $path, 'remove_all_path' => TRUE);
    $zip->addGlob('*.{png,gif,jpg,pdf}', GLOB_BRACE, $options);
    $res = $zip->close();
}
```

What is my mistake? Directory name is correct and it is writable (CHMOD 777).

Comment: `shell_exec('zip output.zip folderToCompress');`

Comment: @Dave: linked answer has not much to do with my question..

Comment: @DanFromGermany: that is in my case not allowed

Comment: Then do you get any error message? You may like to add a `try { ... } catch(\Exception $e) { ... }` block not sure weather your methods throw Exceptions.

Comment: No Errors, no exceptions but I know now why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works (excerpt):

```
$ret = $zip->open($path.'files.zip', ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
...
$options = array('remove_all_path' => TRUE);
$zip->addGlob($path.'*.{png,gif,jpg,pdf}', GLOB_BRACE, $options);
```

Comment: but I'cant get the directory structure removed in the created Zip-File, can someone help me why?

Comment: @user2227400: If you don't pass `add_path` in `$options` array, `remove_all_path` will not take any effect, besides if you pass `'add_path' => ''`, `addGlob` will return `false`.

Comment: how do I set the compression level using `addGlob()`?

Answer (score 0):

Reusing the code from Alireza Fallah in ([How to zip a whole folder using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php)) appling basename to the iteration of files, you´ll have zip without path structure :)

```
function create_zip($files = array(), $dest = '', $overwrite = false) {
    if (file_exists($dest) && !$overwrite) {
        return false;
    }
    if (($files)) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if ($zip->open($dest, $overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file, basename($file));
        }
        $zip->close();
        return file_exists($dest);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function addzip($source, $destination) {
    $files_to_zip = glob($source . '/*');
    create_zip($files_to_zip, $destination);
    echo "done";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely to be the wrong `$flag` argument passed to method `ZipArchive::open ( string $filename [, int $flags ] )`. In your case, it should be `$ret = $zip->open('files.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);`

If zip-file does not already exist, `$ret = $zip->open('files.zip', ZipArchive::OVERWRITE); var_dump($ret);` would print `int(11)`, which is the equivalent value of constant `ZipArchive::ER_OPEN`, whose description is `Can't open file.`.