# how to save multiple excel files in single zip file

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

My excel file code is as below...

```
$dte=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dt));
$fname='Logsheet_'.$dte.'_Zone_' .$zone_id.'.xls';
$filename='Backup.xls'; //save our workbook as this file name
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$fname.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache
//save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
//if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');  
//force user to download the Excel file without writing it to server's HD
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

And then I want to know, how can I change this code, as I can put multiple excel files, into a single zip file as output.

Comment: Ok ...and where is the Problem ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: first save all your files, zip it into 1 file, and offer it to download.

Comment: Create a temporary folder on disk; save each spreadsheet file to that folder (with a different name); open a new zip file, use `addGlob()` to add all the files to the zip, close the zip and send it to user's browser; delete temporary folder and its contents.... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php/4914894#4914894 for how to create a zip file for all the contents of a folder

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I think you are not a professional googler and I did this before but I won't give you the whole solution. In PHP there is a class named `ZipArchive`. It creates zip files on the server. It's very easy to use. The url is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php). The basic workflow is:

- you save the excel file to the server
- get those files into an array
- create an empty zip via `ZipArchive`
- foreach the array of files and add them to the zip file
- Save the zip file
- Send the zip file to header.

`ZipArchive` is pretty well documented and I'm sure you will find the solution there.

Have a nice day!