# add existing folder with content to zip php

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

In php, I can create a zip file using:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zipname = "somename" . '.zip';
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
```

and add files to it with

```
$zip->addFile($pathtodir."filename.bla", "filenameinzip.bla");
```

or I can add a empty folder to it with:

```
$zip->addEmptyDir("foldername");
```

but, is there a way to add a folder which already exists and has sub-content to a zip file directly?

IMPORTANT: the solution in the other thread adds only files in the folder directly to zip, but not the folder itself.  I want to keep the structure, meaning the folder should be in the zip file too, not only its sub-content. like:

```
zipname.zip/foldername/filenameinzip.bla
```

Comment: There are examples on how to do that in the comments of the add function: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zip a whole folder using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: I already read that before I wrote the question, but the answer in the thread adds files directly to the zip, without the folder itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is what you need :
1 - [other ask in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php)
2 - [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addglob.php)

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I can't write comment, I must have 50 rep. I have to delete it ?

Comment: both solutions add only files from the directory to zip, NOT the folder which the files are in. thats what I meant under "IMPORTANT"

Comment: Did you read the "User contribution" in this page http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addemptydir.php ?