# Can't create zip file (php)

Tags: php, zip, archive

So I found this class on the internet that can put files into a zip.
I have a form where I can upload pictures into a folder, then I tried to loop into these files and store them into a zip file but seems I failed somewhere.

> zipper class

```
<?php

class zipper {
    private $_files = array(),
            $_zip;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_zip = new ZipArchive;
    }


    public function add($input){
        if(is_array($input)){
            $this->_files = array_merge($this->_files, $input);
        }else{
            $this->_files[] = $input;
        }

    }
        public function store($location = null){

            if(count($this->_files) && $location){
                foreach ($this->_files as $index => $file) {
                    if(!file_exists($file)){
                        unset($this->_files[$index]);
                    }
                    print_r($file . "<br>");// here gives me the exact path of the files.
                }

                if($this->_zip->open($location, file_exists($location) ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)){
                    foreach ($this->_files as $file) {
                        $this->_zip->addFile($file, $file);
                    }

                    $this->_zip->close();
                }
            }

        }
}
```

> and this is my uploading file

```
> $uniqUser = uniqid(strtoupper($userName). "-" , true); 
> $directory ='../upload/';  
> $file_name is $files['name']

if(!is_dir("../upload/". $uniqUser ."/")) {
                    mkdir("../upload/". $uniqUser ."/");
                }


                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $directory .  $uniqUser . "/" . $file_name)){
                    $uploaded[$position] = $directory . $uniqUser . "/" . $file_name;
                        $zipper = new zipper;
                        $zipper->add(BASE_URL . "/upload/" . $uniqUser . "/" . $file_name);
                        $zipper->store(BASE_URL . "/upload/" . $uniqUser . ".zip");
```

the last code is inside a foreach that loops into the files uploaded.

I don't know why I fail in creating the archive at the end ...

Could be an easy way to turn these new created folders into a zip or add them into a zip ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zip a whole folder using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php)

Comment: I may be wrong and am not in a position to test atm but if i am not mistaken you need to jump through some hoops for file_exists() to work with full url.  Try just passing it the relative location of the file without BASE_URL.  Also throw in some debug lines and tell us more e.i. `if(!file_exists($file)){
  unset($this->_files[$index]);
   print_r("unset" . $file);
 }
 
 and 
 
 foreach ($this->_files as $file) {
  $this->_zip->addFile($file, $file);
   print_r("Added file:" . $file);
 }`

Comment: @ThomasB I get nothing from `print_r("unset" . $file)` means no files have been deleted, and from the `print_r("Added file:" . $file);` I get the 3 files have been added.
I did change the BASE_URL and it worked, but the problem is, after opening the archive I only find the last file uploaded even $file says that has added all but actually only added the last file.

Comment: Added file:../upload/path/7 001.jpg 
Added file:../upload/path/8 001.jpg 
Added file:../upload/path/9 001.jpg  
@ThomasB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem was because I added `BASE_URL` I had to write `../upload/`.
Second problem was kinda stupid ...
I had to create the class outside the foreach `$zipper = new zipper;` and $zipper-`store("../upload/" . $uniqUser . ".zip");`for unnecessary repeating (added it at the bottom).