# Why ZipArchive working not correct?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

This is my code zip 1 file:

```
 $zipname="C:/xampp/htdocs/test/5/JPN/5/5_1.0.pdf.zip"
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
         $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);                     
         $zip->addFile("C:/xampp/htdocs/test/5/JPN/5/5_1.0.pdf");       
         $zip->close();
```

But it zip from folder C:\
[image]

Why ZipArchive working not correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zip a whole folder using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php)

Comment: `open()` returns either TRUE or an error code on failure. `addFile()` and `close()` both return false on failure. What do you see if you check the return values from these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass two parameters in the addFile function.

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php)

> bool ZipArchive::addFile ( string $filename [, string $localname ] )
>
> filename The path to the file to add.
>
> localname local name inside ZIP archive.

This means that the first parameter is the path to the actual file in the filesystem and the second is the path & filename that the file will have in the archive.

The following code will work for you

```
$zip->addFile("C:/xampp/htdocs/test/5/JPN/5/5_1.0.pdf", "5_1.0.pdf");
```

Comment: You're almost there, except that `5_1.0.pdf` is not a valid PHP expression and the compiler triggers a parse error and refuses to run the script.

Comment: oops it was a typo. the name should be in quotes. "5_1.0.pdf" like this

Comment: Of course it should be in quotes. Use the `edit` link under the answer to fix it.