# Compressing and extracting a Directory with all its files using PHP

Tags: php, zip, unzip, php-ziparchive

How to compress or zip a directory and then extract alongside with its files and and sub directories using `php` script.

i have a directory which is needed to be compressed,then transferred to another server and then extracted into a new directory with new name given to it.

```
PATH.'/'.$TO.'/'.$DIR_WITH_DIR_NAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you want to perform `zipping` and `unzipping` operations using `php` it is must to install `php zip` extension,as i am using `Ubuntu` as my OS and `php7.0` on my server i installed it using this command.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip
```

For zipping parent directory and other sub directories along side with its files you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php) given in approved answer.i have used it myself and its best to do so.

Transfer file using `php cURL` to other server.Now to unzip a folder in a new folder whichever you are trying to extract files in,first create that directory using this php code.

```
@mkdir(PATH.'/'.$TO.$NEW.'/'.$DIR_WITH_DIR_NAME,0777,true);
```

This will create the directory and give it all read/write permissions
now use this code to extract a directory

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open(PATH.'/'.$TO.$COMPRESSED.'/'.$FILE.'.zip') === TRUE) {

    if(is_dir(PATH.'/'.$TO.$NEW.'/'.$DIR_WITH_DIR_NAME)){
    $zip->extractTo(PATH.'/'.$TO.$NEW.'/'.$DIR_WITH_DIR_NAME);
    }
    $zip->close();
    echo 'extracted';
} else {
    echo 'error in file extracting';
}
```

That's it all of the files will be extracted into newly created directory enjoy happy coding.