# TYPO3 isDir, getRealPath don't work on the Controller

Tags: php, zip, typo3

What i would like to do, is to zip my fileadmin and my extension folder with a zipAction on my controller. So i took a piece of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914807/7162477)
and i have this:

```
$fileAdminPath = 'fileadmin';
$archiveName = $importerSettings['fileadminArchiveName'];
$zip = new \ZipArchive;
$zip->open($archiveName, \ZipArchive::CREATE | \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$files = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator (new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($fileAdminPath), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY);

if (!$file->isDir()) {
   // Get real and relative path for current file
   $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
   $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($fileAdminPath) + 1);
   // Add current file to archive
   $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();
```

Now, when the code reaches the `isDir()` part, i get the following error:

> Call to a member function isDir() on null

If i remove it and let the code run again, the `getRealPath()` gets the same error. So i am guessing i missing a namespace or something like that, that stores these functions.

On a local php file (index.php) and MAMPP it works. On TYPO3, not.

By the way, i am not sure if the controller really reads the fileadmin path. If i got it wrong, please feel free to correct me.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your script inside an extension, this script is searching `fileadmin` within your extension directory.

Try to use the following script:

```
$fileAdminPath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('fileadmin');
```

**Edit:**

You should also walk the files in an foreach because you scan an directory recursiv:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
  if (!$file->isDir()) {
    // Get real and relative path for current file
    $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
    $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($fileAdminPath) + 1);
    // Add current file to archive
    $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
  }
}
```

Comment: i added it your code and it found the fileadmin i would like to have. But, it doesnt make the error go away! +1 for the fileadmin tipp!

Comment: This foreach loop solve my problem! Thank you very much @René Pflamm !!!