# Convert Folder into zip using php

Tags: php, zip

I'm trying to convert a folder into zip using php i found code on the internet and try to use it and it did nothing? so my question is that is there nay extension to do this or library ?

```
$rootPath = realpath('E:\dir\sub_dir');

// Initialize archive object

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('sub_dir.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

$files = scandir($rootPath);
unset($files[0], $files[1]);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($dir.'\\'.$file);
}
$zip->close(); // enter code here
```

Comment: Here is what you need, duplicate another: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php)

Comment: Already try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zip a whole folder using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php)

Comment: i ask the question about what extension.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to add/enable the PHP ZIP extension to properly open or write zip files. After installing this, do make sure that this extension is enabled at .ini.Hope this helps!

For more info, visit [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) link.
A similar post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php?noredirect=1&lq=1). Do check this

Comment: I'm using wordpress so how can i add this into wordpress

Comment: i add the extension .dll in xamp folder and enable in php.ini file but still the same result

Comment: i wrote the code above will you please see if there is something missing

Comment: Add this at the top of ur php page and check for errors: ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

Comment: still nothing frustrating thing ever in my life

Comment: Have you restarted Apache?

Comment: yes when i run the file it show there is processing running but in result it shows nothing