# Multiple Image file how to zip in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have multiple image in folder, and I get it on href button. So how to zip that file in codeigniter.

Here is my View Code:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()."index.php/itr1/download/".$key['pan_card']."/".$key['previous_itr'] ?>" name="images">Downalod All Attachments</a>
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public function download()
{
    // File path
    $id =  $this->uri->segment(3); 
    $id1 =  $this->uri->segment(4); 

    $filepath1 = FCPATH.'upload/'.$id;
    $filepath2 = FCPATH.'upload/'.$id1;

    $filename = "backup.zip";
    $this->zip->download($filename);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zip a whole folder using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php)

Comment: You can probably copy the required images in a temp folder and then use the solution mentioned here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

with CI its really simple CI has zip library you can use to zip data, files or folder and download them here is how you can create zip and download

```
$id =  $this->uri->segment(3); 
$id1 =  $this->uri->segment(4); 

$this->load->library('zip');

$filepath[] = FCPATH.'upload/'.$id;
$filepath[] = FCPATH.'upload/'.$id1;

foreach($filepaht as $file) {
  $this->zip->read_file($file);
}

// Download the file to your desktop. Name it "my_backup.zip"
$this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
```

Read more about zip library here

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/zip.html

Comment: Call to undefined method CI_Loader::read_file and also this error

Comment: so how load zip liabrary

Comment: its core library available in CI you can find in system/libraries folder

Comment: @umefarooq you can add zip library by writing `$this->load->library('zip');`

Comment: @JaiminVyas yes you can add library by writing.