# Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: Unknown error

Tags: php, zip

I have a strange error in PHP, where I traverse a lot of directories and archieve the old stuff by ZIP'ing the folder and then delete the folder with all its files inside. This works for the most part fine, but for a few entries I get this error:

> Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file:
> Unknown error in
> myfile.php on
> line 132

I have this PHP code, taken directly from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914807/2028935 but I inserted an `exit()` to make sure to catch an error:

```
// Get real path for our folder
$rootPath = realpath("/myfolder/pathX");

// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open("/myfolder/myfile.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir()) {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
if(!$zip->close()) {
    exit();
}
```

The error is triggered on line **132** which is this line, `if(!$zip->close()) {`

I don't have folder or file permission problems, as the folder and files do get deleted (another code), but I cannot figure out what the `Unknown error` is in ZIP?

I am using PHP 7.4 on a Windows Server.

**### UPDATE ###**

It seems the unknown error is due to the ZIP file path being too long, but I don't understand why. If the path in `$zip->open("/myfolder/myfile.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);` is longer than or equal to **250** characters, then it comes with this error!?

I could understand if there would be a limit with 256 or 260 characters, as I can see there could be some limits there, but why 250?

Currently I am investigating if I can reduce the path length by doing a local drive/folder mapping with the DOS command `SUBST` or through registry, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices`

Comment: Which line is that happening on?

Comment: Updated post - it is on `if(!$zip->close()) {`

Comment: What do you mean by it happening "for a few entries"? If it happens when you close the zip file, how do you know which entries it's happening on?

Comment: Because ZIP'ing is just a part of the code. I run through a list of directories. I can see the error as depicted on the entries which fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more analysis I found that the `Unknown error` was due to the ZIP file path was too long - it was longer than **250** characters, which seems to be a Windows limitation, though I see fluctuating numbers on this limit, anything from 247 to 260.

One possible solution I tried was doing a `SUBST` command in DOS command, which creates a drive for the long path - like this `subst O: D:\very\long\..\path`. This will give a `O:\` where I can connect directly but this only works for my local user account nor does it survive a reboot.

The solution that I found working, was adding a new `REG_SZ` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices` in the registry. I added this `REG_SZ` (string):

> O: => \DosDevices\D:\very\long...\path

[image: Insert this in to the registry]

After a reboot of the Windows Server (2019) I now have the O-drive, that I can use within IIS (and by then PHP) and my problem has been solved :-)